# Adding lists of models to another list of models

Tags: c#, list, model, addition

I have two lists of models which I want to add to a third list of models but I get an error - `No overload for method "Add" takes two arguments`.
Here's my code:

```
List<TableNotificationModel> one = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TableNotificationModel>>(cmdPositive);
List<TableNotificationModel> two = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TableNotificationModel>>(cmdNegative);
List<TableNotificationModel> three = new List<TableNotificationModel>();
three.Add(one, two);
                

IEnumerable<TableNotificationModel> result = three;
DataSourceResult dataSource = result.ToDataSourceResult(request);
```

I want to set the list `result` to the value of `three` so that I can use it below.
I tried using `AddRange` instead of `Add` but it throws the same error.
Some of the developers where I intern told me to look into `Dictionary` but I
can't figure out how to fix this with dictionary.

I tried something like this `three.Add(one)` but it says `cannot convert generic list to model`.

Any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: You are trying the wrong things. First try to explain what the relationship is between items in `one` and items in `two`? Should it just be a union of the two list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is if it should just be a flat list of items (union):

```
var one = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TableNotificationModel>>(cmdPositive);
var two = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TableNotificationModel>>(cmdNegative);
var three = one.Union(two).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `AddRange()`.
`Add` takes a single object while `AddRange()` takes an `IEnumerable` of objects.

So,
`three.AddRange(one);`